# How to make a table in a doublepage with sidewaystable

Tags: tables, double-sided, sidewaystable

I'm struggling with a table that I can't get to fit successfully into the page.

I want to clarify that I am working with TeXlive 2019 (it is not feasible to upgrade before finishing the project) and therefore the `tabularray` package is not an option.

I've already tried different solutions but I can't get it to fit:

1. I've made use of the `makecell` package which has helped but it hasn't been enough.
2. I tried using the `sidewaystable` environment of the `rotating` package, but even reducing the font to the smallest size (`\tiny`) it doesn't fit on the page.
3. I've transposed it, but as it's a 10 x 11 table it doesn't make much difference.
4. That's why the `longtable` package doesn't seem to be an option either.

So my idea is to be able to create the table in a double page (landscape legal size) where it can fit without problems, but is it possible to do that in LaTeX? How could it be solved?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{%
  fontsize=10pt,
  headsepline=on,%
  footinclude=on,%
  paper=7in:8.5in,%
  DIV=calc,%
  BCOR=4mm,%
  parskip=half+% 
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Entrevistad}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
% First attempt with transposed table
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption[Tabla transpuesta]{Tabla de datos transpuestos.}
  \label{tab:transpuesta}
  \centering\tiny
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.07\linewidth}*{11}{p{0.075\linewidth}}} 
    \toprule
    \rothead{Nombre} & \rothead{Entrevistada A} & \rothead{Entrevistada B} & \rothead{Entrevistada C} & \rothead{Entrevistada D} & \rothead{Entrevistada E} & \rothead{Entrevistada F} & \rothead{Entrevistada G} & \rothead{Entrevistada H} & \rothead{Entrevistada I} & \rothead{Entrevistada J} & \rothead{Entrevistada K}\\ 
    \midrule 
    \textbf{Edad} & 36  & 33 & 31 & 50 & 30 & 35 & 31 & 40 & 36 & 37 & 26 \\
    \textbf{Nacionalidad} & Italiana & Argentina & Mexicana & \textcolor{blue}{Italiana} & Mexicana & Mexicana & Guatemalteca & \makecell[l]{Mediterránea\\-oeste\\ \textcolor{blue}{Española}} & Mexicana & Mexicana & Mexicana \\
    \textbf{Género} & \makecell[l]{Mujer/\\ no binario} & Mujer & Mujer & Mujer & Mujer & Mujer & \makecell[l]{Mujer\\ cisgenero/\\ prefiere no\\ identificarse} & \makecell[l]{No\\ binario} & Mujer & Muje~ & \makecell[l]{Mujer\\ trans} \\
    \makecell[l]{\textbf{Clase}\\ \textbf{social}} & Media & Media & Trabajadora & \textcolor{blue}{Media} & Trabajadora & \makecell[l]{Media,\\ antes\\ Trabajadora} & Media & \makecell[l]{Trabajadora,\\ Media,\\ Alta/\\ \textcolor{blue}{Media}} & \makecell[l]{Media\\ alta} & Media & \makecell[l]{Media\\ alta} \\
    \makecell[l]{\textbf{Raza}/\\ \textbf{etnia}} & Caucásica & \makecell[l]{Latina\\ \textcolor{blue}{Blanca}} & \makecell[l]{Prefiere no\\ identificarse/\\ \textcolor{blue}{Mestiza}/\\ \textcolor{blue}{Morena}} & \textcolor{blue}{Blanca} & Mestiza & \makecell[l]{Mexicana\\ Blanca} & \makecell[l]{Mestiza\\ \textcolor{blue}{Blanca}} & \makecell[l]{Mediterránea,\\ Latina\\ \textcolor{blue}{Blanca}} & Latina & Latina & Latina \\
    \textbf{Estudios} & Doctorado & \makecell[l]{Universidad/\\ especialidad en\\ ciberseguridad} & \makecell[l]{Universidad\\ (Antropología\\ social)} & Bachillerato & Universidad & Bachillerato & \makecell[l]{Universidad\\ (Antropología)} & Universidad & Doctorado & Universidad & Bachillerato \\
    \textbf{Profesión} & SysAdmin & Investigadora & FrontEnd & \textcolor{blue}{Programadora} & & \makecell[l]{coordinación\\ de\\ repositorios\\ y perspectiva\\ programadora} & \makecell[l]{Tech and\\ data\\ strategy} & \makecell[l]{Desarrolladora\\ de software} & \makecell[l]{Ingeniera en\\ computación} & \makecell[l]{Licenciada en\\ informática}  & Programadora \\
    \makecell[l]{\textbf{Posición}\\ \textbf{en la}\\ \textbf{organización}} & SysAdmin & \makecell[l]{Líder de\\ proyecto} & FrontEnd Jr. & \makecell[l]{Directora\\ de su\\ empresa} & Integrante & Empleada & \makecell[l]{Tech and\\ data\\ strategy} & Desarrolladora & \makecell[l]{Investigadora,\\ profesora} & \makecell[l]{Desarrolladora\\ de software} & \makecell[l]{Senior\\ Engineer} \\
    \makecell[l]{\textbf{Tiempo}\\ \textbf{en la}\\ \textbf{organización}} & 4 años & 2 años & 5 meses & & 4 años & 1 año & 6 meses & independiente & & 4 años & 4 meses\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

% Second attempt with the table rotated 90°
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \begin{table}[H]
    \caption[Tabla resumen.]{Tabla que resume algunos de los datos.}
    \label{tab:data}
    \centering\tiny
    \begin{tabular}{
      p{0.09\linewidth}%
      p{0.05\linewidth}%
      p{0.08\linewidth}%
      p{0.07\linewidth}%
      p{0.07\linewidth}%
      p{0.07\linewidth}%
      p{0.09\linewidth}%
      p{0.09\linewidth}%
      p{0.07\linewidth}%
      p{0.07\linewidth}%
      }
      \toprule
      \thead{Nombre} & \thead{Edad} & \thead{Nacionalidad} & \thead{Género} & \thead{Clase} & \thead{Raza/\\ etnia} & \thead{Estudios} & \thead{Profesión} & \thead{Pos.\\ en Org} & \thead{Años\\ en org} \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada A & 36 & Italiana & \makecell{Mujer\\/no binario} & Media & Caucásica & Doctorado & SysAdmin & SysAdmin & 4 años \\ 
      \midrule
      Entrevistada B & 33 & Argentina & Mujer & Media & \makecell{Latina\\ \textcolor{blue}{Blanca}} & \makecell{Universidad\\/especialidad en\\ ciberseguridad} & Investigadora & \makecell{Líder de\\ proyecto} & 2 años \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada C & 31 & Mexicana & Mujer & Trabajadora & \makecell{Prefiere no\\ identificarse\\  \textcolor{blue}{Mestiza/}\\ \textcolor{blue}{morena}} & \makecell{Universidad\\ (Antropología\\ social)} & Frontend & Frontend Jr. & 5 meses \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada D & 50 & \textcolor{blue}{Italiana} & \textcolor{blue}{Mujer} & \textcolor{blue}{Media} & \textcolor{blue}{blanca} & \textcolor{blue}{Bachillerato} & \textcolor{blue}{programadora} & \makecell{\textcolor{blue}{directora}\\ \textcolor{blue}{de su}\\ \textcolor{blue}{empresa}} & \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada E & 30 & Mexicana & Mujer & Trabajadora & Mestiza & Universidad & & integrante & 4 años \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada F & 35 & Mexicana & Mujer & \makecell{Media,\\ antes\\ trabajadora} & \makecell{Mexicana,\\ blanca} & Bachillerato & \makecell{coordinación\\ de repositorios\\ y perspectiva\\  programadora} & Empleada & 1 año \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada G & 31 & Guatemalteca & \makecell{Mujer\\ cisgénero/\\ prefiere no\\ identificarse} & Media & \makecell{Mestiza\\ \textcolor{blue}{blanca}} & \makecell{Universidad\\ (antropóloga)} & \makecell{Tech and\\ data strategy} & \makecell{Tech and\\ data strategy} & 6 meses \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada H & 40 & \makecell{Mediterránea\\-Oeste\\ \textcolor{blue}{Española}} & No binaria & \makecell{Trabajadora\\/media\\/alta\\ \textcolor{blue}{Media}} & \makecell{Mediterránea,\\ latina\\ \textcolor{blue}{blanca}} & Universidad & \makecell{Desarrolladora\\ de software}  & desarrolladora & independiente \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada I & 36 & Mexicana & Mujer & Media alta & latina & Doctorado & \makecell{ingeniera en\\ computación} & \makecell{Investigadora\\ profesora} & \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada J & 37 & Mexicana & Mujer & Media & latina & Universidad & \makecell{licenciada\\ en\\ informática} & \makecell{Desarrolladora\\ de software} & 4 años \\
      \midrule
      Entrevistada K & 26 & Mexicana & Mujer trans & Media alta & Latina & Bachillerato & Programadora & \makecell{Senior\\ engineer} & 4 meses \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't embed a `table` env. in a `sidewaystable` env. I.e., do get rid of `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` in the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution employs a `sidewaystable` environment and, importantly, does away with all `\thead` and `\makecell` directives. That way, line breaking can be determined automatically (and optimally) by LaTeX instead of on a case by case basis. Since you're using the `\tiny` relative font size, I also reduced the value of `\tabcolsep` by 50%, from 6pt (the default) to 3pt. The main result of these changes is that the table now fits on a single page.

Separately, I would also replace most `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace` to give the table a more open and inviting "look".

To avoid some confusion: I have (obviously) nothing against the `makecell` package and its `\thead` and `\makecell` directives. But since the OP is allowing automatic line-breaking in all columns anyway, one might as well make use of this freedom instead of painstakingly attempting to find suitable break points in cells.

Reducing the font size of the caption is left as an exercise to the reader...

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{%
  fontsize=10pt,
  headsepline=on,%
  footinclude=on,%
  paper=7in:8.5in,%
  DIV=calc,%
  BCOR=4mm,%
  parskip=half+% 
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans,euler,inconsolata}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,rotating}
%\usepackage{longtable,float}

%% new:
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1\linewidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} % switch to landscape mode, start a table env.
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\centering
\tiny
    \caption[Tabla resumen.]{Tabla que resume algunos de los datos.}
    \label{tab:data}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}
      P{0.05} l P{0.09} P{0.11} P{0.08} P{0.08} P{0.10} P{0.14} P{0.09} C{0.07}
      @{}}
      \toprule
      Entrevistada & Edad & Nacionalidad & Género & Clase & Raza\slash etnia & Estudios & Profesión & Pos. en~Org & Años en~org \\
      \midrule
      A & 36 & Italiana & Mujer\slash no~binario & Media & Caucásica & Doctorado & SysAdmin & SysAdmin & 4 años \\ 
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      B & 33 & Argentina & Mujer & Media & Latina \newline \textcolor{blue}{Blanca} & Universidad\slash especialidad en ciberseguridad & Investigadora & Líder de proyecto & 2 años \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      C & 31 & Mexicana & Mujer & Trabajadora & Prefiere no identificarse \textcolor{blue}{Mestiza\slash morena} & Universidad (Antropología social) & Frontend & Frontend Jr. & 5 meses \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      D & 50 & \textcolor{blue}{Italiana} & \textcolor{blue}{Mujer} & \textcolor{blue}{Media} & \textcolor{blue}{blanca} & \textcolor{blue}{Bachillerato} & \textcolor{blue}{programadora} & \textcolor{blue}{directora de su empresa} & \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      E & 30 & Mexicana & Mujer & Trabajadora & Mestiza & Universidad & & integrante & 4 años \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      F & 35 & Mexicana & Mujer & Media, antes trabajadora & Mexicana, blanca & Bachillerato & coordinación de repositorios y perspectiva programadora & Empleada & 1 año \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      G & 31 & Guatemalteca & Mujer cisgénero\slash prefiere no identificarse & Media & Mestiza \textcolor{blue}{blanca} & Universidad (antropóloga) & Tech and data strategy & Tech and data strategy & 6 meses \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      H & 40 & Mediterránea-Oeste \textcolor{blue}{Española} & No binaria & Trabajadora\slash media\slash alta \textcolor{blue}{Media} & Mediterránea, latina \textcolor{blue}{blanca} & Universidad & Desarrolladora de software  & desarrolladora & independiente \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      I & 36 & Mexicana & Mujer & Media alta & latina & Doctorado & ingeniera en computación & Investigadora profesora & \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      J & 37 & Mexicana & Mujer & Media & latina & Universidad & licenciada en informática & Desarrolladora de software & 4 años \\
      \addlinespace %\midrule
      K & 26 & Mexicana & Mujer trans & Media alta & Latina & Bachillerato & Programadora & Senior engineer & 4 meses \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```